# Find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^5b+3$ and $ab^5+3$ are both perfect cubes of integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Are there integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^5b+3$ and $ab^5+3$ are both perfect cubes of integers? $a,b$ are distinct integers.

P.S.: *I think trying to find some special cases would not be helpful*.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase as "Find all pairs $(a,b)$ of integers..." if you want a full solution. Also you might include a particular solution, if you know of one, to back up the idea there may be "lots of a,b".

Comment: In the PS now, it seems finding a particular solution is not what the OP wants. So my previous comment still stands: If OP wants *all* solutions, the question should say that. (Actually if anyone has found a particular solution I would like to see it as a comment.)

Comment: I think there's  a solution here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377800/usajmofind-the-integer-solutionsab53-x3-a5b3-y3?rq=1